# Tyring to validate a form through Javascript, however code just isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTML form that I need to be custom validated through Javascript before being submitted. However, despite following the code from my textbook, my form submits without validating.

I'm a Graphic Design student in an Advanced Web markup class (don't be fooled by the name, its essentially Javascript 101). 
This is my first time using Javascript, and we're using Javascript: The Web Warrior 6th Edition as our textbook. I apologize in advance if there is a simple solution to this, but like I said, I'm super new to Javascript.

Our assignment is to create a form for our website and then use Javascript to stop the form from submitting and validate all the inputs. If the inputs are valid, then the form submits as it should. If they aren't, then its suppose to indicate which fields are invalid by highlighting the correct fields and through an error message.

I used the textbooks chapter work-along files as the basis for my code. However, it's not working. I'm not sure if it's not loading the Javascript or what. I've validated all my code (everything's fine apparently) and contacted my professor for help, but I haven't heard back (the assignment was due on 4/26 and I've already submitted it, but I want to know what went wrong).

I've had luck with getting the form to validate with try/catch/finally statements but that's not what I'm supposed to be doing here according to the lesson. I've tried plugging other stuff in and attempting every kind of fix that made the slightest bit of sense to me (and some that didn't).

```
"use strict"; // interpret document contents in JavaScript strict mode

/* global variable */
var formValidity = true;

/* validate required fields */
function validateRequired() {
 var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("input[required]"); // 
 selects everything with input and required
 var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
 var contactBoxes = document.getElementsByName("contact");
 var fieldsetValidity = true;
 var elementCount = inputElements.length;
 var currentElement;
 try {
  for (var i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) { // loop statement to check 
 each field
     // this validates all required input elements in fieldset
     currentElement = inputElements[i];
     if (currentElement.value === "") {
        currentElement.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)"; // changes 
input to pink if error
        fieldsetValidity = false;
     } else {
        currentElement.style.background = "white";
     }
  }

  if (!contactBoxes[0].checked && !contactBoxes[1].checked) {
     // verify that a crust is selected
     contactBoxes[0].style.outline = "1px solid red";
     contactBoxes[1].style.outline = "1px solid red";
     fieldsetValidity = false;
  } else {
     contactBoxes[0].style.outline = "";
     contactBoxes[1].style.outline = "";
  }

      if (fieldsetValidity === false) { // this is the error shown in the 
 div
           throw "Please complete the indicated field(s) so we may 
provide better service.";
      } else {
         errorDiv.style.display = "none";
         errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
      }
   }
   catch(msg) { // this throws the error if there are any
      errorDiv.style.display = "block";
      errorDiv.innerHTML = msg;
      formValidity = false;
   }
}

function validateNumbers() { // this makes sure the phone number field 
allows 
only numbers
  var pNumNot;
  var pNum = document.getElementById("phoneinput");
  var numErrMsg = document.getElementById("errorNumber");

   try {
      if (isNaN(pNum.value) || pNum.value === "") {
         pNumNot = true;
      } else { // phone input value is a number
         pNum.style.background = "";
         numErrMsg.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (pNumNot) {
          throw "Please use numbers only.";
      }
   }
   catch(msg) {
      if (pNumNot) { // phone input is not a number
         pNum.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
         numErrMsg.style.display = "block";
         numErrMsg.innerHTML = msg; // then this message will display
      }
      formValidity = false;
   }
}

/* validate form */
function validateForm(evt) {
   if (evt.preventDefault) {
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting
   } else {
      evt.returnValue = false; // prevent form from submitting in IE8
   }
   formValidity = true; // reset value for revalidation
   validateRequired();
   validateNumbers();
   if (formValidity === true) {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
   } else {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please 
complete 
the indicated field(s) so we may provide better service.";
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
   }
}

/* create event listeners  */
function createEventListeners() {
   var orderForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
   if (orderForm.addEventListener) {
      orderForm.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
   } else if (orderForm.attachEvent) {
    orderForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", validateForm);
 }
}

/* run initial form configuration functions */
function setUpPage() {
   createEventListeners();
}

/* run setup functions when page finishes loading */
if (window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener("load", setUpPage, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onload", setUpPage);
}
```

I can post my HTML code if needed. 
The form is supposed to turn the input fields that are empty pink and show an error message. Also, the phone number input field is only supposed to allow numbers. If everything is valid, it should just submit and load a new page that thanks the user.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: share html code

Comment: Does the callback function when submitting prevent default (a [link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault))?

Comment: A suggestion: there's an option to add a code snippet to your question. Rather than copy/pasting the entirety of your code, I suggest creating a small example of what you're trying to do (example: a single text input that only accepts numbers or a required radio selection). It sounds like the issue is submitting the form without validation, but this would be different than incorrect validation (code says an input is valid when it's not).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your form keeps submitting without validation is because you did not call the `event.preventDefault()` in the listener handling the submit event. 
Plus since the required attribute is set you don't need to check the input values for empty strings.

I recommend you read eloquent JavaScript to get a good handle of event listeners. And you can read up form validation on the Mozilla developer network (MDN).

Comment: So I thought that since I added the event preventDefault() in the validateForm function, that I just had to call on that in the createEventListeners function..? I apologize for being an idiot and needing more clarification. My textbook and lectures didn't really go over the preventDefault event for more than a paragraph.